# Do we need the fundamental theorem of Galois theory in Galois' proof of the Abel-Ruffini theorem?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory

Admittedly, my question is a bit provocative. Let me be precise.

The fundamental theorem of Galois theory states three things (for a fixed finite normal separable extension $M/K$):

(1) The maps $L\mapsto \mathrm{Gal}(M/L)$ and $H\mapsto \mathrm{Fix}(H)$ determine an anti-isomorphism between the poset of intermediate fields of $M/K$ and the poset of subgroups of $\mathrm{Gal}(M/K)$.

(2) For each intermediate field $L$, $|\mathrm{Gal}(M/L)| = [M:L]$ and for each subgroup $H$ of $\mathrm{Gal}(M/K)$, $[M:\mathrm{Fix}(H)]=|H|$.

(3) $L$ is a normal extension of $K$ if and only if $\mathrm{Gal}(M/L)$ is a normal subgroup of $\mathrm{Gal}(M/K)$.

The main ingredient of Galois' proof of the Abel-Ruffini theorem is the following theorem that I will denote by $(*)$: a polynomial $f$ over $\mathbb Q$ is solvable if and only if $\mathrm{Gal}(f)$ is solvable.

Certainly the proof of $(*)$ uses (3) of the fundamental theorem of Galois theory to translate between the solvability of $f$ and $\mathrm{Gal}(f)$.

**Question:** Does the proof of $(*)$ use (1) somewhere? Or can one prove $(*)$ without proving (1)?

Comment: Any reason why we should not use the fundamental theorem of Galois theory ?

Comment: @Peter I don't say we should not use it. I ask whether we *have to* use it.

Answer (score 0):

At least one of the previous lemmas needed on the proof that I remember uses it:

**Lemma 3**
Let $L/K$ be a finite Galois extension of prime degree $p$.
Suppose $char(K) = 0$.
Then $L/K$ is a prime radically solvable extension.

Proof:
Let $\Omega$ be an algebraic closure of $L$.
Let $\zeta$ be a primitive $p$-th root of unity in $\Omega$.
$\color{blue}{\textrm {Then $L(\zeta)/K(\zeta)$ is a Galois extension and\\
$Gal(L(\zeta)/K(\zeta))$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $Gal(L/K)$.}}$
Hence it is a cyclic group of order $p$ or $1$.
By Lemma 2, $L(\zeta)/K(\zeta)$ is a prime radically solvable extension.
On the other hand, by another previous lemma $K(\zeta)/K$ is a prime radically solvable extension.
Hence, by Lemma 1, $L(\zeta)/K$ is a prime radically solvable extension.
Hence $L/K$ is a prime radically solvable extension.
**QED**